# Access violation reading location - creating matrix class

Tags: c++, oop, matrix

This is supposed to be my HW  in OOP course. SO i asked to create matrix class. Code works fine -  all methods and new operands works fine BUT when my D`tor is empty and when i write there code to free memory i get this error. Thanks for help

```
int main()
{
MyMatrix m1(3, 3);
MyMatrix m2(3, 3);
MyMatrix res(3, 3);

m1.Set();
m2.Set();

cout << m1;
cout << m2;

res = m1 + m2;

cout << res;

}
```

CPP

```
MyMatrix::MyMatrix(int row, int col) // C`tor with specific data
{
n = row;
m = col;

matrix = new int* [n]; // Memory  allocation for rows

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = new int[m]; // Memory Allocation for columns
}


for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {

        matrix[i][j] = 0;

    }
}
}

MyMatrix::~MyMatrix() // Default d`tor 
{

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    delete[] matrix[i];
}
delete[] matrix;
}

void MyMatrix::Set()
{
cout << "Enter new row" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {

        cin >> matrix[i][j];

    }

    if (i != (n - 1))
    {
        cout << "Enter new row" << endl;
    }

  }
}


ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const MyMatrix& matrix)
{

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.n; i++)
{

    //run in loop on every column.
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.m; j++)
        //print value with a space.
        out << matrix.matrix[i][j] << "t";
    //at the end of every row jump line.
    out << endl;
}

out << endl;
return out;
}


MyMatrix& MyMatrix::operator= (const MyMatrix& mat1)
{
n = mat1.n;
m = mat1.m;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {

        matrix[i][j] = mat1.matrix[i][j];

    }

}

return *this;

}

const MyMatrix MyMatrix::operator+(const MyMatrix& mat1) const
{
MyMatrix temp(n, m);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
    {

        temp.matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j] + mat1.matrix[i][j];

    }

}

return temp;

}
```

H file

```
class MyMatrix
{

private:

int **matrix;
int n, m;

public:

MyMatrix(int a, int b);
~MyMatrix();

void Set();

const MyMatrix  operator+ (const MyMatrix& mat1) const;
MyMatrix& operator= (const MyMatrix& mat1);

friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const MyMatrix& matrix);
};
```

Comment: *Code works fine* -- No it doesn't.  The destructor is exposing the bugs in your code.  Put it back and fix the bugs.  Second, where is your copy constructor for `Matrix`?  Third, your assignment operator introduces a memory leak, and is way off as to the proper way to perform a copy of `Matrix`.

Comment: *SO i asked to create matrix class* -- You could have simply used `std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;` and not have any of the issues you're having now.

Comment: Worth reading: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op Note how it uses a 1D array and performs the math to do the 2D to 1D indexing. This is much faster and as you can see, much simpler than mucking about with arrays of arrays.

Comment: Also give [What is the Rule of Three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) a read. It will pre-emtively answer what's probably going to be the next question.

Comment: It is hard to answer a question like this without practically writing the code correctly.  The current code needs much more than a couple of minor adjustments.